# How to run a background service to give alerts in android?

Tags: android, background-service

I am working on an android application but the problem is that I have to alert user through a message on notification bar which will occur after ten(10) days ,like in candy crush game it gives alert of full lives after some hours. I am a beginner in android so I am confused about the implementation of this scenario. Please guide me of its implementation with code.

Answer (score 2):

You can do so with the [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) and the [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html)

#### AlarmManager

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, TimeAlarm.class);
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(AndroidAlarmService.this, 0, myIntent, 0);

AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 10);
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```

#### BroadcastReceiver

```
public class TimeAlarm extends BroadcastReceiver {

  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent paramIntent) {

     // Request the notification manager
     NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

     // Create a new intent which will be fired if you click on the notification
     Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW");

     // Attach the intent to a pending intent
     PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

     // Create the notification
     Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.icon, "Something new!"), System.currentTimeMillis());
     notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, "Something new!", "Description",pendingIntent);

     // Fire the notification
     notificationManager.notify(1, notification);
 }

}
```

Comment: how to implement it.please help me with some code or example